# Can we think of relativity as a measure to determine the finiteness of universe?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, universe, faster-than-light

Let’s consider a hypothetical situation wherein an observer is in the standpoint of a light ray. The observer faces infinite time dilation. Thus time stops for the observer and it'd have transversed an infinite distance for any finite time to pass for a stationary observer. What should we conclude from this?

The universe is infinite? or

The universe is expanding faster than the speed of light? or

The photons are travelling an infinite distance around the closed finite universe?

Comment: A light ray has no rest frame, so it is impossible for the rest frame of an observer to coincide with the rest frame of a light ray.

Answer (score 3):

Your first sentence is already not defined. If by "standpoint of a light ray" you mean "a hypothetical observer travelling at the speed of light", you are already in undefined territory. The [Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation), which mathematically tell us how to change between [inertial reference frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference) contain a factor: $$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}},$$ which is equal to infinity if $v=c$ (check this). So isn't not even sensible to talk about a hypothetical observer travelling at the speed of light, special relativity is not mathematically defined at this point.

If we do one day find that massive particles *can* travel at the speed of light, special relativity will become an outdated theory that breaks down in this limit just as classical mechanics breaks down at relativistic (near light) speeds.

Comment: can we assume the observer to be massless (for the time being)?

Comment: @aniket Unfortunately not, if we want to make predictions in physics (for instance "what would an observer travelling at the speed of light see?"), this has to be done mathematically. If what you're asking for is not mathematically defined that doesn't *necessarily* mean it *can't* happen (since physics only produces *models* of the real world) but it does mean that our model cannot answer your question.

Comment: thanks man, got it!

Comment: @Charlie This is a fantastic answer. However, I don't think it's good practice to say that $\gamma$ is infinity when $v=c$, because this is exactly the vernacular _that encourages nonsense reasoning about massless observers going at the speed of light._ A division by zero alone should show that the hypothetical observer cannot be considered. You might think this is too pedantic, but what I'm trying to say is that laymen can take the sentence too literally rather than understand it in terms of limits.

Comment: @MaximalIdeal You're right, I have given this answer a few times now when questions like this have been asked and I have previously used limits, however to someone *completely* unfamiliar with physics (and by extension the mathematics involved) the notation of limits might be a bit hard to read, so as in this instance I simply say it is equal to infinity, even if a little loosely.